# Как в Putty поменять путь к исполняемому файлу PHP?

Tags: php, putty

Добрый день! Мой проект находится на удалённом хостинге reg.ru и в самом проекте мне нужно загрузить модуль, я подключилась через ssh к командной строке putty и при любого ввода команды возникает ошибка: -bash: /usr/bin/php5: No such file or directory. А мой путь выглядит примерно так: /opt/php/5.6/bin/php. Как можно в putty поменять путь к исполняемому файлу php?

Comment: Какая конкретно команда? Если это скрипт php который вы запускаете в консоле как программу в начале его есть строка #!/usr/bin/php5 или подобная. Там надо поменять путь на Ваш.

Comment: @ErroR Спасибо большое, разобралась. Нужно было просто на хостинге в файле поменять путь к исполняемому файлу php alias php='/usr/bin/php5' на alias php='/opt/php/5.6/bin/php'!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто на хостинге в файле поменять путь к исполняемому файлу php

```
alias php='/usr/bin/php5'
```

на

```
alias php='/opt/php/5.6/bin/php'!
```

Comment: Зачем alias? Почему не symlink? Ну или в PATH /opt/php/5.6/bin добавить...

Comment: @vp_arth Потому что там уже было прописано alias.. А зачем ещё над этим заморачиваться? я эту строку не стала менять а просто прописала полный путь

Comment: Однажды, например, вы захотите выполнить скрипт по крону, или из php скрипта... А алиасы только в самом шелле работают. Я не настаиваю, разумеется, ваше дело.

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо большое за информацию, буду знать.. Я начинающий программист и про все эти штуки ещё не знаю..Но я на заметку себе это поставила))